# How do i make ActiveRecord work on Tables with multiple columns as Primary keys?

Tags: activerecord

How do i use ActiveRecord on existing DB with multiple columns as primary key and no ID column? I had to write extensions/hacks on set_primary_key, update and delete methods. But im not sure if it'll work on future versions. Is there a way to make ActiveRecord work in such cases without hacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord doesn't support composite primary keys. [Here is a library](http://compositekeys.rubyforge.org/) that purports to add support though.